# Ember - Can't get route from controller when defining custom controller with controllerName

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to bind a custom controller for a route by using:

```
# app/routes/products/category.coffee

`import Ember from 'ember'`

route = Ember.Route.extend

  controllerName: 'categories/selector'

`export default route`
```

This works, but when I try to bubble events from that controller to the route it gets in a recursive loop.

I found that this is because the custom controller can't get to the route, because `'target'` is the controller:

```
# app/controllers/categories/selector.coffee

`import Ember from 'ember'`

controller = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  actions:
    back: ->
      console.log "controller back action handle"
      console.log (@ == @get 'target') # => true
      return false # Returning true creates recursive loop

`export default controller`
```

The template:

```
# app/templates/products/category.hbs

{{render 'categories/selector'}}
```

Is this normal behavior? How would I get to the route from this custom controller?

Comment: Can you make a http://emberjs.jsbin.com ?

Comment: Can't reproduce the behavior.. Could it be something in EmberCLI? I'll post my full route and controller.. (Here's the bin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wenivewoge/1/edit?html,js,console,output )

Comment: Don't post *everything*, show us a minimal test case.

Comment: I found the problem, in the view I used `{{render 'categories/selector'}}`, changing this to `{{partial 'categories/selector'}}` fixed it. Something to do with creating another controller instance?

Comment: Yes, `render` creates its own context/controller.

Comment: That explains it, thanks for your help, trying to reproduce led me to the problem, should do that more often.. ;)

Comment: Do you want to add an answer so we can close this question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the template, you should be using:

```
# app/templates/products/category.hbs

{{partial 'categories/selector'}}
```

`render` creates its own context/controller, as stated by @givanse.